# What is wrong in java code?

Tags: java, if-statement, enums

I am trying to generate a digit to execute switch statement but it is not generating proper result. But when the IF block is removed it works properly. What is the problem in the code?

```
import static java.lang.Character.isDigit;
public class TrySwitch
{
  enum WashChoise {Cotton, Wool, Linen, Synthetic }
  public static void main(String[]args)
        {

        WashChoise Wash = WashChoise.Cotton;
        int Clothes = 1;
         Clothes = (int) (128.0 * Math.random());
         if(isDigit(Clothes))
         {
            switch (Clothes)
            {
                case 1:
                System.out.println("Washing Shirt");
                Wash = WashChoise.Cotton;
                break;
                case 2:
                System.out.println("Washing Sweaters");
                Wash = WashChoise.Wool;
                break;
                case 3:
                System.out.println("Socks ");
                Wash = WashChoise.Linen;
                break;
                case 4:
                System.out.println("washing Paints");
                Wash = WashChoise.Synthetic;
                break;

            }
                switch(Wash)
                {
                    case Wool:
                    System.out.println("Temprature is 120' C "+Clothes);
                    break;
                    case Cotton:
                    System.out.println("Temprature is 170' C "+Clothes);
                    break;
                    case Synthetic:
                    System.out.println("Temprature is 130' C "+Clothes);
                    break;
                    case Linen:
                    System.out.println("Temprature is 180' C "+Clothes);
                    break;

                 }              
                }   
         else{
             System.out.println("Upps! we don't have a digit, we have  :"+Clothes );
                  }
        }

}
```

Comment: what does "doesn't work properly" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is that the isDigit method is meant for characters and detecting whether they represent a number. For example `isDigit(8) == false` because 8 maps to backspace in ASCII, but `isDigit('8') == true` since '8' is really 56 in ASCII.

What you might want to do is remove the if altogether and change your random generation to always produce a number between 1 and 4. This can be done as follows:

```java
Clothes = ((int) (128.0 * Math.random())) % 4 + 1;
```

The `% 4` will make sure the value is always between 0 and 3, and the `+ 1` shifts the range to 1 to 4.

You can also use the Random class included with java:

```java
import java.util.Random;
...
Clothes = new Random().nextInt(4) + 1
```

Once again the `+ 1` shifts the range to be 1 to 4 inclusive.

Answer (score 3):

You are not using isDigit() properly, it takes a char as an argument, not an int, see this link: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/character_isdigit.htm

Answer (score 1):

isDigit() essentially tests for an ascii value in the range 48-57, ie, characters which are digits.  Chances are, that's not what `Clothes` is.

http://www.asciitable.com/